Interpretation of negative coefficients in ordinal regression in spss
I have built an ordinal regression (logit) in the spss for data in the likert scales. I put the independent variables into factors, not covariates. As far as I understand, this should be done with ordinal scales.
How to correctly interpret the output results in the SPSS?
The example of results:
dependent variable = [1] coef = -4.56
dependent variable = [2] coef = -2.33
...
dependent variable = [5] coef = -0,84
factor 1 = [1] coef = -1,2
factor 1 = [2] coef = -0,8
...
factor 1 = [5] coef =  0^a
factor 2 = [1] coef = -0,8
factor 2 = [2] coef = -0,4
...
factor 2 = [5] coef =  0^a
factor 3 = [1] coef = - 1,22
factor 3 = [2] coef = - 0,99
...
factor 3 = [5] coef =  0^a
Do I understand correctly that negative coefficients show that the probability of marking a lower score in the dependent variable increases if you select a low score in the factor?
What do negative coefficients in the dependent variable mean?

Welcome to Cross Validated!  To me, this situation seems to call for coaching/mentoring rather than Q & A on a site like this.

Modeling independent variables as ordinal is tricky. It's not enough that you put them in the "factor" box, you should specify a linear or polynomial contrast for them. I'm not sure if this is possible in SPSS ordinal logistic regression (it's possible in binary logistic). Maybe through some type of syntax. Now (I think, hard to say without more info) you have modeled them as non-ordered factors.
